# Вывод фона за пределы контейнера

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В блоке в центральной части есть блок, который разделен на две части, в правом блоке у текста есть фон который идет от начала текста до правого края экрана,
центральная часть не меняется(центрирован через margin).

Какие есть способы это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно поместить центрирующий контейнер внутрь блока, и половину блока заполнить фоном:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 70%;
}

section {
  background: #cda;
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.block {
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/be/Bliss_location%2C_Sonoma_Valley_in_2006.jpg/300px-Bliss_location%2C_Sonoma_Valley_in_2006.jpg) no-repeat right center/50% auto;
}

.block__container {
  display: flex;
}

.block__item {
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="container block__container">
    <div class="block__item"></div>
    <div class="block__item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <section></section>
</div>
```

Или псевдоэлементом

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 70%;
}

section {
  background: #cda;
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.block:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/be/Bliss_location%2C_Sonoma_Valley_in_2006.jpg/300px-Bliss_location%2C_Sonoma_Valley_in_2006.jpg) no-repeat center/cover;
}

.block__item {
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="block__item"></div>
    <div class="block__item"></div>
  </div>
  <section></section>
</div>
```

Comment: я так понимаю если блоки не пропорциональные то все ровно размер(before) считается через проценты?

Comment: Ширина псевдоэлемента здесь считается в единицах `viewport` : 50vw - 50% ширины экрана. Если дочерние блоки не равны друг другу, тогда для псевдоэлемента нужно задать `left:ширина левого блока` и высчитать ширину через `calc`

Comment: Например, если левый блок имеет ширину 100px, а правый занимает всё отсальное место, то `block:before{left:100px;width:calc(50vw + 50% - 100px)}`